# Is there a way to define custom html for an empty DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a `Datatable` that could be empty - I know about the `language.emptyTable` (https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.emptyTable) option, but I'd like to not just display text if the table is empty, but render custom HTML.

Is there a recommended way to do this in the table's settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify `html` in `emptyTable` config.

default value will be

> Value: No data available in table

But you can render any HTML instead of default string

```
"emptyTable": "<h1>Empty table custom html</h1><div><span>any span</span></div>"
```

```js
var columnDefs = [{
  title: "Column 1"
}, {
  title: "Column 2"
}];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#table').DataTable({
    "language": {
      "emptyTable": "<h1>Empty table custom html</h1><div><span>any span</span></div>"
    },
    columns: columnDefs,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />

<table id="table"></table>
```